Почему put запрос работает как то странно на vue3 and express?
У меня есть фронт на vue3 composition api:
 const updateUser = async () => {
  try {
    await axios.put(`http://localhost:3000/update`, user.value)
      VueCookies.remove('user')
    VueCookies.set('user', user.value, '30d');
    console.log('User updated')
  } catch {
    console.error('Ошибка в редактирование профиля');
  }
}

и вот бэк на node.js express:
    app.put("/update", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const newUser = req.body;
    await User.findOneAndReplace({ email: newUser.email }, newUser, {
      new: true,
      upsert: true,
    });
  } catch {
    console.error(505);
  }
});

но почему то у меня не работает остальные команды на фронте после put запроса, я даже пытался все убрать и просто в консоль что то написать но все равно нет, я попробывал сделать фронт вот так:
const updateUser = async () => {
  try {
    await axios.put(`http://localhost:3000/update`, user.value,
      VueCookies.remove('user'),
      VueCookies.set('user', user.value, '30d'),
      console.log('User updated'))
  } catch {
    console.error('Ошибка в редактирование профиля');
  }
}

И вот так все заработало, но почему я не понимаю :))))) И у меня такие ошибка встречаются часто в проектах при чем не только с put запросами, мне кажется, что я чего-то не знаю)

А вы вообще поняли что поменяли?

нет я понимаю что это не правильно, но почему то это работает)
